# C3 Chart shows negative y-Labels

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I'm using the C3 chart library and I specified a graph showing money values. The money values are all `>= 0`.

Now if I have a graph with values between 15.000 and 20.000 the y-Axis will only show a domain from roughly `[13.000 - 22.000]`.

Instead for that example I want it to show `[0 - 22.000]`.

My idea was to use the `axis: { y: { min : 0 }}` property, which almost worked. Now my problem is that 0 is a few pixels above the x-Axis, which means depending on the scale of course I get something like `[-2.000 - 22.000]`.

Can I somehow force the negative values to be avoided completely?

```
c3.generate({
    ...
    axis : {
        y : {
            tick : {
                format: d3.format("$,")
            },
            min : 0
        },
        ...         
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
c3.generate({
    ...
    axis : {
        y : {
            tick : {
                format: d3.format("$,")
            },
            min : 0,
            padding : {
              bottom : 0
            }
        },
        ...         
    }
});
```

You can read more about the API here:
http://c3js.org/reference.html

This setting is named padding.bottom.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. The padding can also be used for the y-axis to prevent that tiny space between the y-axis and the first data point, which looks bad especially for (stacked)-area-charts. Using `y : { ... padding : { left: 0 }}` the graph data starts directly at the y-axis.